Compose UI not waiting for viewModel's coroutine results. GoogleMap composable
I have a compose screen that shows Google Maps. I'm using this state model:
data class CragsOnMapsState(
    val currentLocation: Location? = null,
    val cragsList: List<Crag>,
    val gymsList: List<Gym>,
    val cragsButtonPressed: Boolean
)

currentLocation always starts as null.
I want the map to start pointing at the user's location and to get the location I do this on the VM:
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(
        CragsOnMapsState(
            cragsList = listOf(),
            gymsList = listOf(),
            cragsButtonPressed = true
        )
    )
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        _state.update {
            CragsOnMapsState(
                cragsList = cragsList,
                gymsList = gymsList,
                cragsButtonPressed = true
            )
        }
        getCurrentLocation()
    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.update {
                it.copy(currentLocation = locationTracker.getCurrentLocation())
            }
            Log.i("test getCurrentLoc state", state.value.currentLocation?.latitude.toString())
            Log.i("test getCurrentLoc state", state.value.currentLocation?.longitude.toString())
        }
    }

I know that locationTracker.getCurrentLocation() works because it prints the location's correct values when I call Log.i.
My issue is that, when the screen starts, it doesn't points to the returned coordinates, but to (0,0) because, at this moment, state.currentLocation is still null
GoogleMap(
    properties = mapProperties,
    cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
          CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
              LatLng(
                 state.currentLocation?.latitude ?: 0.0,
                 state.currentLocation?.longitude ?: 0.0
              ),
              6f
           )
    },
)

How can I do it in order for the screen to wait for the VM's coroutine result before showing the map so it doesn't start with the location as null? or how can I tell the GoogleMap composable that state.currentLocation changed so it moved to the desired coordinates?
